# Convert integer to categorical vector of fixed size in Python

Tags: python

I have a set of N integers with the range of values to be from 1-6. I would like to produce the corresponding categorical vector of size 6 per each integer (therefore an array of size Nx6) which will be the categorical representation of my initial set. In the case that my integer will be 1 the result should be:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

While for 6:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

And etc..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please publish any code you have.

Comment: You want what ? there is no `set` in your question - only two `list`'s. Please show [mcve] - input data and output data in sufficient amount so we can get what you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> [int(i+1 == x) for i in range(6)]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

>>> x = 6
>>> [int(i+1 == x) for i in range(6)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Likewise for an `Nx6` list of lists:

```
>>> X = [4,1,5]
>>> [[int(i+1 == x) for i in range(6)] for x in X]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, this can be achieved efficiently with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

m, n = 6, 10
L = np.random.randint(1, m+1, n)  # construct array of 10 numbers between 1 and 6

A = np.zeros((n, m))              # initialize array of zeros
A[np.arange(n), L-1] = 1          # use advanced indexing to assign values
```

The result is a NumPy array which you can then index via `A[0]`, `A[1]`, etc.

```
print(A)

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.fill_diagonal` to fill diagonals with value of your need:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((6, 6), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 1)

print(a)
```

**Output**:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0]                                               
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]                                               
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]                                               
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]                                               
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Now, if your integer is 1, use `a[0]`,... for 6, use `a[5]`.

Eg:

```
input_integer = 1
print(a[input_integer-1])

# [1 0 0 0 0 0]
```